# Sequel accessing many_to_many join table when adding association

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'm building a wishlist system using Sequel. I have a `wishlists` and `items` table and an `items_wishlists` join table (that name is what sequel chose). The `items_wishlists` table also has an extra column for a facebook id (so I can store opengraph actions), which is a NOT NULL column.

I also have `Wishlist` and `Item` models with the sequel many_to_many association set up. The `Wishlist` class also has the `:select` option of the many_to_many association set to `select: [:items.*, :items_wishlists__facebook_action_id]`.

Is there a way that I can add in extra data when creating the association, like `wishlist.add_item my_item, facebook_action_id: 'xxxx'` or something? I can't do it after I create the association as the facebook id is has NOT NULL on the column.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recommended way to do this is to add a model for the join table.  However, if you don't want to do that, you can do:

```
class Wishlist
  def _add_item(item, hash={})
    model.db[:items_wishlists].insert(hash.merge(:item_id=>item.id, :wishlist_id=>id))
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. If I made a model for the join table, how would I set up the relations so I can do `wishlist.items`? Also I presume I would just create an instance of the join model when I want to associate an item with a list - am I correct?

Comment: Would be nice to show an example of what you say is the recommended solution here

Answer (score 2):

I think there is also another possibility.

First a MWE (minimal working example) of your question:

```
  require 'sequel'
  Sequel.extension :pretty_table  #Sequel::PrettyTable.print()/Sequel::PrettyTable.string()

  DB = Sequel.sqlite
  DB.create_table(:wishlists){
        primary_key :id
        String :listname
  }
  DB.create_table(:items){
        primary_key :id
        String :descr
    }
  DB.create_table(:items_wishlists){
        primary_key :id
        foreign_key :wishlist_id, :wishlists
        foreign_key :item_id, :items

        add_column :facebook_id, type: :nvarchar
  }

  class Item < Sequel::Model
    many_to_many :wishlists 
  end

  class Wishlist < Sequel::Model
    many_to_many :items
  end

  w1 = Wishlist.create(listname: 'list1')
  w1.add_item(Item.create(descr: 'item 1'))
  #w1.add_item(Item.create(descr: 'item 2'), facebook_id: 'fb2')  ##<- This does not work

  #Sequel::PrettyTable.print(Wishlist)
  #Sequel::PrettyTable.print(Item)
  Sequel::PrettyTable.print(DB[:items_wishlists])
```

To allow `ad_item`with a parameter (`Wishlist#add_item(Item.create(descr: 'item 2'), facebook_id: 'fb2')`) you must define an `adder` as in this example:

```
require 'sequel'
Sequel.extension :pretty_table  
Sequel::PrettyTable.print()/Sequel::PrettyTable.string()

DB = Sequel.sqlite
DB.create_table(:wishlists){
      primary_key :id
      String :listname
}
DB.create_table(:items){
      primary_key :id
      String :descr
  }
DB.create_table(:items_wishlists){
      primary_key :id
      foreign_key :wishlist_id, :wishlists
      foreign_key :item_id, :items

      add_column :facebook_id, type: :nvarchar
}

class Item < Sequel::Model
  #~ many_to_many :wishlists 
end

class Wishlist < Sequel::Model
  many_to_many :items, 
                join_table: :items_wishlists, class: Item,
                left_key: :wishlist_id, right_key: :item_id, 
                adder: (lambda do |item, facebook_id: nil|
                      self.db[:items_wishlists].insert(wishlist_id: self.id, item_id: item.id, facebook_id: facebook_id)
                end)
end

w1 = Wishlist.create(listname: 'list1')
w1.add_item(Item.create(descr: 'item 1'))
w1.add_item(Item.create(descr: 'item 2'), facebook_id: 'fb2')

Sequel::PrettyTable.print(DB[:items_wishlists])
```

The result:

```
+-----------+--+-------+-----------+
|facebook_id|id|item_id|wishlist_id|
+-----------+--+-------+-----------+
|           | 1|      1|          1|
|fb2        | 2|      2|          1|
+-----------+--+-------+-----------+
```

But the next problem will come later:

With `w1.items` you get the list of items, but you have no access to the parameters. (at least I found no way up to now. I'm still researching, but I expect, that I need a model of the join table for this (see Jeremys recommendation))